# Animate background of an h1 element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

The background doesn't change even when including jQueryUI or when trying to change to a simple color, like `'red'`, instead of `linear-gradient()`.

```js
$('#the-button').click(function() {
  $('#something').animate({
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, blue, white)"
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #000;
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: arial;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 id="something">Something</h1>
</div>
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="Animate">
```

You can see the full code at https://codepen.io/KaiZoDa128/pen/WNNOYaZ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery cannot animate linear gradients.

Comment: So I should try to code it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't animate a gradient (at least with CSS, I guess the same goes with jquery). And for the simple color test, it's simply that gradients, which are images, "cover" the background color, so if your element has a gradient and you add a background color you won't see it.

**But** you could *maybe* do it with CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.